# How can I loop through an array of divs to show() them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show

first post.. experienced with programming but not so much jQuery/javascript.
I have some divs that are hidden at first, and they are assigned id's in ascending order:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".over_map").each(function(i) {
          $(this).attr('id', "over_map" + (i + 1));
          // console.log($(this));
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Now I want to loop through a dynamic number of these divs and show them. If (eventually, not implemented yet) an SQL call returns 4 records, I would want to show() 4 of the hidden divs. Seems like this should be simple but I am missing something.. limited internet access unfortunately, but I didn't find any stack overflow entries pertaining to it.. any help appreciated!

Comment: It depends totally upon how you want to pick the 4 hidden divs to show.  You will have to describe that part of your operation before anyone can answer this question.

Comment: `$(document).find('div').each(function(i,v){$(v).show();});`

Comment: `$(".over_map:hidden").show();`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set of elements in a jQuery object, you don't need to loop them at all - just call `.show()` on the set.

e.g.

```
$('#over_map1, #over_map3').show();
```

If you have a list of ids that you want to show, you can build the selector string:

```
function buildSelector(ids) {
  var selectors = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    selectors.push("#over-map" + ids[i]);
  }
  return selectors.join(", ");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var ids = [1, 3];
  $(buildSelector(ids)).show();
});
```

Demo at http://codepen.io/precise54/pen/nkyzg

Comment: Hm this does work nicely however if I wrap those divs in a container div it breaks. Something I don't get about how id selectors behave ? hrmmm